# How to stream OpenCv image from webcam to http server

Tags: python, opencv

I am attempting to send an image from a webcam on a RasPi to an Http server, so that when I open it on my Robot I can actually get the image. I know how to use openCV in a window, and I have been able to create a server I can open in my browser, my question is simply how to display the openCV feed on said server.

FYI, I am trying to get this working on a computer before fighting with the RasPi, so the RasPi is not currently an issue I am concerned with.

```
#Current Code
import cv2
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import time
from io import StringIO
import PIL
from PIL import Image
hostName = 'localhost'
hostPort = 7153

#run camera
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

def updateCamFeed():
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
    out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', fourcc, 20.0, (640,  480))

    while True:
         ret, frame = cap.read()


class MyServer(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
     def do_GET(self):

        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(bytes("<html><head><title>WebCam Display</title> 
 </head>", "utf-8"))
        self.wfile.write(bytes("<body><p><a href=\"output.avi\">Image</a> 
    </p>", "utf-8"))
        self.wfile.write(bytes("<p>It Worked!!!!! %s</p>" % self.path, 
    "utf-8"))
        self.wfile.write(bytes("</body></html>", "utf-8"))
def main():

# initialize server

    myServer = HTTPServer((hostName, hostPort), MyServer)
    print(time.asctime(), "Server Starts - %s:%s" % (hostName, hostPort))
    myServer.serve_forever()
    updateCamFeed()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This will send the file to the server, but will not display it in a window

Answer (score 0):

I meant opening the server on my computer, which is connected to the mentioned robot. Just trying to help with any confusion